# How to split data into two graphs with mat plot lib

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, graph, ode

I would be so thankful if someone would be able to help me with this. I am creating a graph in matplotib however I would to love to split up the 14 lines created from the while loop into the x and y values of P, so instead of plt.plot(t,P) it would be plt.plot(t,((P[1])[0])))  and
plt.plot(t,((P[1])[1]))).  I would love if someone could help me very quick, it should be easy but i am just getting errors with the arrays

`

```
#Altering Alpha in Tumor Cells vs PACCs
#What is alpha? α = Rate of conversion of cancer cells to PACCs
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files
value = -6
counter = -1
array = []
pac = []
while value <= 0:
  def modelP(x,t):
      P, C = x
      λc = 0.0601 
      K = 2000 
      α = 1 * (10**value) 
      ν = 1 * (10**-6) 
      λp = 0.1 
      γ = 2
  

    #returning odes
      dPdt = ((λp))*P*(1-(C+(γ*P))/K)+ (α*C) 
      dCdt = ((λc)*C)*(1-(C+(γ*P))/K)-(α*C) + (ν***P) 
      return dPdt, dCdt



  
  

    #initial
  C0= 256 
  P0 = 0 
  Pinit = [P0,C0]
    

    #time points 
  t = np.linspace(0,730) 

    #solve odes
  P = odeint(modelP,Pinit,t) 
  plt.plot(t,P)
  value += 1 
  
  
  
  
  #plot results
  

plt.xlabel('Time [days]')
plt.ylabel('Number of PACCs')

plt.show()
```

`

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subplots()` to create two subplots and then plot the individual line into the plot you need. To do this, firstly add the subplots at the start (before the while loop) by adding this line...

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1) ## Plot will 2 rows, 1 column... change if required
```

Then... within the while loop, replace the plotting line...

```
plt.plot(t,P)
```

with (do take care of the space so that the lines are within while loop)

```
if value < -3:  ## I am using value = -3 as the point of split, change as needed
    ax[0].plot(t,P)#, ax=ax[0])  ## Add to first plot
else:
    ax[1].plot(t,P)#,ax=ax[1])   ## Add to second plot
```

This will give a plot like this.

[image]